# Effective model for calculating momentum or growth rate for a time series

Tags: statistics, algorithms, regression

I have a series of numbers tracking the performance of an entity on any given day.  It's nothing but a simple integer for each date.  For example, here's a series for Entity "X"

```
11/1/2012 - 11/30/2012 - 3000 (one month summary)
12/1/2012 - 123
12/2/2012 - 129
12/3/2012 - 131
12/4/2012 - 112
...
12/31/2012 - 147
```

Ultimately I'm trying to output some form of momentum indicator for this entity for a day, week, and month.  My initial attempts were as follows:

1. I could simply calculate the slope between two points.  For daily, I would compare day 1 versus day 2 and take the slope.  For weekly, the average count for week 1 and compare to average count for week 2, etc.
2. Use a theoretical formula for detecting whether or not the count is "breaking out" of a local or global maxima (up) or minima (down) and assign a value based on the distance from the local or global maxima/minima.  Unfortunately I'm not sure how one would approach calculating this.
3. An additional formula that determines whether or not the trend created in #2 is actually sustained.

My question is this: in a very simple time series, is there a relatively straight-forward approach to coming up with a momentum indicator?  Obviously there are flaws with a simple equation but the more simple the better.  I can improve the equation over time.

*One assumption:* There are no other variables to be taken into consideration aside from this number.  All other things are constant.

Comment: One initial thought: moving averages may be the most efficient system if we're sticking with simple.